# Create variable in data frame using another column's Quartile value

Tags: r, quartile

I want to create a variable in a data frame, that would categorize the observations based on a column's Quartile/Median value.

Below is what I tried.

```
Name<-c("name1","name2","name3","name4","name5","name6")
Age<-c(49,12,29,55,25,19)

df9<-data.frame(Name,Age)

df9$catoG[df9$Age<=quantile(df9$Age,0.25)]<-"Young"
df9$catoG[df9$Age>quantile(df9$Age,0.25) & df9$Age<=median(df9$Age)]<-"Adult"
df9$catoG[df9$Age>median(df9$Age)]<-"Elder"
```

The output I received is

```
   Name Age catoG
1 name1  49 Elder
2 name2  12 Young
3 name3  29 Elder
4 name4  55 Elder
5 name5  25 Adult
6 name6  19 Young
```

Is there a more efficient way in R that I can achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cut` is your friend for all tasks involving splitting vectors in ranges:

```
df9$new = cut(df9$Age, 
              breaks = c(-Inf, quantile(df9$Age,c(0.25, 0.5)), Inf), 
              labels = c('Young', 'Adult', 'Elder') )

#   Name Age catoG   new
#1 name1  49 Elder Elder
#2 name2  12 Young Young
#3 name3  29 Elder Elder
#4 name4  55 Elder Elder
#5 name5  25 Adult Adult
#6 name6  19 Young Young
```

Comment: Ok. so, is it in anyway more efficient than dplyr? Because dplyr is the one I've been playing with for a while. But good to know about cut. thank you !

Comment: Its somewhat a matter of preference. In this instance I would say this is more efficient, yes, because it only calls `quantile` once.  Whereas the dplyr solution calls `quantile` twice and also `median`.  A lot of base R functions including `cut` are very well optimised.  But there are also some tasks where packages such as dplyr (or data.table, which is my preference) can be very helpful.  I don't really see what benefit dplyr brings in this particular case

Comment: I would also say that if you had more than three categories to split, the `case_when` approach would quickly get cumbersome, whereas `cut` remains a simple clean approach no matter how many ranges you split into.

Comment: Very true, at least in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dplyr::mutate`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html) and [`dplyr::case_when`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) from the `dplyr` package :

```
Name<-c("name1","name2","name3","name4","name5","name6")
Age<-c(49,12,29,55,25,19)

df9<-data.frame(Name,Age)

df9 %>% mutate(catoG = case_when(Age<=quantile(Age,0.25) ~ 'Young',
                                 Age>quantile(Age,0.25) & Age<=median(Age) ~ 'Adult',
                                 TRUE ~ 'Elder'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function creates a quantile(n) group vector from a numerical vector (so n = 4 for quartiles):

```
qgroup = function(numvec, n = 4){

  qtile = quantile(numvec, probs = seq(0, 1, 1/n))
  out = sapply(numvec, function(x) sum(x >= qtile[-(n+1)]))

  return(out)
}
```

Applying the function on your data:

```
Name = c("name1","name2","name3","name4","name5","name6")
Age = c(49,12,29,55,25,19)

df9 = data.table(Name,Age)
df9[, Q := qgroup(Age)]

> df9
    Name Age Q
1: name1  49 4
2: name2  12 1
3: name3  29 3
4: name4  55 4
5: name5  25 2
6: name6  19 1
```

Lastly, we label the quartile groups:

```
labels = list('Young', 'Adult', 'Elder', 'Elder')

df9[, Label := sapply(Q, function(x) labels[x])]
> df9
    Name Age Q Label
1: name1  49 4 Elder
2: name2  12 1 Young
3: name3  29 3 Elder
4: name4  55 4 Elder
5: name5  25 2 Adult
6: name6  19 1 Young
```